# Python3 List of tuples to tuples as a method argument

Tags: list, python-3.x, tuples

## Problem

Convert a list of tuples into tuples for an argument in a method.

## Example

Method that takes multiple unnamed tuples below:

```
def a(self, *tuples, **kwargs):
```

I have a list of tuples, l

```
l = [('1a', '1b', '1c'),('2a', '2b', '2c'),('3a', '3b', '3c')]
```

Trying to call method a() like this and adding a namedVar for **kwargs:

```
a(('1a', '1b', '1c'),('2a', '2b', '2c'),('3a', '3b', '3c'),namedVar=1)
```

## Attempts

Tried this:

```
>>> (i for x in l)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1107882b0>
```

and this:

```
>>> *l
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

Comment: `my_object.a(*l,namedVar=1)` ?

Comment: That works for the method call. How can I expand the list without a method call. If I try it on its own, I get the `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here` error.

Comment: _expand to what_? Which type would this expanded object have?

Comment: At first I was thinking, print() but then realized this is a method. Would you put your comment as a solution so I can accept it?

Comment: You have two different questions. One is passing a sequence of arguments to a function that takes *args, the other is how to flatten a sequence. For the latter, try `[item for tup in l for item in tup]`